# Assessing the security of Amazon WorkMail: exploring alternative measures beyond two-factor authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, security

I have recently started exploring Amazon WorkMail as a potential email solution for my organization, but I noticed that it doesn't seem to support two-factor authentication (2FA). As security is a top priority for us, I am concerned about this apparent gap in protection.

Are there any other security features or best practices within Amazon WorkMail that help compensate for the absence of 2FA? What additional measures can we implement to ensure the security of our email communications?

I would appreciate any insights or recommendations from the community to help me better understand the overall security of Amazon WorkMail.

Comment: As as interesting as this question is, it is not about programming, so is not a good fit here. There is a Software Recommendations site in the Stack Exchange fold - perhaps you could check their on-topic guidance to see if this would fly there. Good luck!

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws